# Save an uploaded photo in a variable

Tags: php, css, forms

This is the form that allow uploading a photo

```
$form['image'] = array(
'#type' => 'file',
'#title' => t('Image'),
'#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'));
```

I have too a list of all availble libray evry library has a php file and a css file to draw a specific graph type like piechart, linechart...

```
 $form['library'] = array(
'#title' => 'Library',
'#description' => t('Select a library'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => $this->get_libraries(),
'#default_value' => $this->options['library'],
 );
```

How can I save the photo in a variable and send it to the CSS file the selected library name. For example the user have selected a photo : image.png and the library pieChart, how to send the selected photo to the css file of the selected library to be used as a background photo of the graph.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [imagecreatfrompng()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) to put the image into a php file, just make sure you use the `.php` extension. CSS has to be handled Client Side, unless you `echo` or `print` a string of CSS upon submission. I recommend making the CSS in advance on a separate page. If you need to do CSS on the fly, use JavaScript.

Comment: can you develop more your ansewer

Comment: Click the `imagecreatfrompng()` link. You can use JavaScirpt to write over or add an HTML `class` attribute using `Element.className = 'newStyleClass';` or `Element.className += ' anotherStyleClass';` , and have the CSS already on the external CSS page like `.newStyleClass{}` or `.newStyleClass.anotherStyleClass{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set css image dynamically, but you can use jquery to load user's image to element which you want.

Comment: how with jquery? for changing the background automatically this is will be enough <style type="text/css">
.logo {
background: #FFF url(<?php echo $variable_holding_img_url; ?>);
}
</style>

Comment: you can set a tag with user's image's name value, then change the background-image of the tag that you want with jquery.